# TFS 2013 build - class library build output path doesn't mean anything?

Tags: c#, tfs, build, tfsbuild

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have a solution that consists of two Web sites and two class libraries. One of the class libraries is a shared library for use within many of our projects so its output is stored a shared location (D:\Applications\SharedLibraries\Bus_logic) so we can reference the dll from there. We have this directory structure on our local machines and build server.

This works perfectly fine on my local machine. Building the solution locally pushes the updated dll to the local D:\Applications\SharedLibraries\Bus_logic folder. Our old CCNet builds would do the very same on the build server.

However, with TFS the output path of a class library doesn't seem to matter. I have a CI build for the solution and the class libraries never get outputted to that path. They're just grouped together in the drop folder.

Is there any easy way to make sure the build copies those dlls to their rightful locations, or do I have to create a custom build template for every one of my solutions that compiles shared libraries so that the dlls get copied to the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a but with TFS builds recently so I hope the following helps.

Before you do any of the following I recommend you create a new build definition and new build template (via Edit Build Definition -> Process -> New Template -> Copy from existing) to test this works.

TFS provides a custom path for the OutDir argument to MSBuild, the variable passed for this is called outputDirectory. The step where this is set is deep within the default build template here, open it and navigate you way to Run On Agent -> Try Compile, Test and Associate -> Sequence -> Compile, Test and Associate -> Try Compile and Test -> Compile and Test -> For Each Configuration -> Compile and Test -> Initialize Variables, once there you'll find a task called Initialize OutputDirectory which by default is set to the 'BinariesDirectory/Platform/Configuration' folder. You could change this to your own custom logic.

It might be an easier way be to set the OurDir argument to nothing on the Run MSBuild task as I assume this will then use the projects default paths. This can be found here in the template, Run On Agent -> Try Compile, Test and Associate -> Sequence -> Compile, Test and Associate -> Try Compile and Test -> Compile and Test -> For Each Configuration -> Compile and Test -> If BuildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild -> For Each Project -> Try to Compile the Project -> Compile the Project.

There is probably a more elegant way via tinkering with the solution or project files but I am not aware of that just yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two good ways to make this light up.

1. Check the dll's in - you can create a folder in source with the files that you depend on checked in. Then add a mapping in the build to get them to a well known location.
2. You can have the DLL's packaged as a NuGet package and take a dependency on that.

## 1 is cheap and cheerful and proan ro error, but not as much as your current solution. #2 is the right way to do things. NuGet was designed to solve these sorts of issues.